# Area 51 proposal disappeared

Tags: support, area-51, specific-proposal

I posted a proposal (Men @ 40) at Area 51 with two suggested questions. I thought the questions were relevant but it seems that others didn't; both were at scores of -5 at the same time. Now it says 0 proposals in my profile and I can't find the proposal any where. It would be nice if I was informed that it was canned.

The proposal is less than 2 weeks old.

Comment: Men @ 40 in denial?

Comment: Denial? No such section on my profile page, anywhere else to look for denial?

Comment: Don't take my comments serious, I'm better ignored...

Comment: Welcome to MSE @Tung, if you plan to stick around, better get used to the humorous side, which is minor but still exists. :)

Comment: I'm all for humour, thank you for the quick responses, almost as quick as @rene's wit ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The requirements for keeping a proposal going are listed when you submit the idea.

Men @ 40 had two example questions and one follower. It was removed by Community♦ on Nov 12th for not meeting the minimum activity requirements for a proposal submitted to Area 51.

[Minimum Activity Requirements for Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20966/minimum-activity-requirements-for-area-51)

Comment: Do you need **both** the sample questions **and** the followers? Because there's an [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92236/color-pencil-art) with no questions but 7 followers that's still open after 15 days.

Comment: I see the within `3 days` part, guess I did not reading the T&C - how weird that an IT guy not read the T&C ;-)  It would be nice to get a notification even if it is a link to the T&C, that we all read, ever time...

Comment: @Catija The feature was designed to need ***both*** criteria, but it currently set to allow *either* while we see how it works in actual practice (works exceedingly well, by the way).